# Maven repository with OAuth2 (or any other HTTP header authentification)

Tags: maven, gradle, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use a Gitlab repository as private maven repository for my dependencies. The deployment process works fine (similar [as described here](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/)), but much more simplified).

No I am trying to add the dependency, which does not seem to work. In maven, this seems to be possible ([as described here](https://ubs-soft.com/maven-private-repository-in-gitlab/)). But in Gradle only BasicAuth or s AWS s3 tokens [seem to be supported](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html).

Is there any way to add custom headers to the requests to a maven repository? Or is there any way to use OAuth2-authentification?

If not, can you give me a hint where to start to implement it?

Comment: Why not using one of the open source repository managers like Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva ?

Comment: I don't want another piece to deploy, maintain, update and monitor. It is just for one library for now. If the Gitlab way does not work, I will try bitbucket or s3.

Comment: First I bet it will become more and the time your are investing already is more than to setup Nexus, Archiva ...from my point of view...furthermore it would make other things easier...

Comment: I agree, I would tell me the same. And I have other clients/projects where this is completely true and where I am setting up another part of infrastructure, because I know that there will be more libraries in future. But in this special project it is very unlikely that there will be more than 1 or 2 libraries/artifacts. It will make things easier, but it will make things more complicated as well, because we will have to maintain another part of infrastructure. No, in this case I won't deploy anything new. I will try Gitlab, and if this does not work, I will use S3, bitbucket, or paid bintray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, I implemented it in Gradle and the pull request got merged (since some time ago already...): https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:http-header-auth

So this is possible now using just Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

[The best piece of information](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/oauth2-authentication-for-remote-repositories/12354) I could get is 2 1/2 years old and it's from a Gradle core dev :

> Currently this is not possible. We want to potentially support more
>   authentication schemes but there are no plans to support OAuth2 at
>   this time.

There is also this 3 years old confidential [Gradle Git Repo Plugin](https://github.com/layerhq/gradle-git-repo-plugin) but there is a "big" counterpart :

> Private maven repos however, aren't easily accessible via the standard
>   maven http interface, or at least I haven't figured out how to get the
>   authentication right. This plugin simply clones the repo behind the
>   scenes and uses it as a local repo, so if you have permissions to
>   clone the repo you can access it.

So basically you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks, @ToYonos. I did not find the first link you mentioned, thanks for this one. You are right, I am stuck... I will try to implement a generic HTTP header authentication theme in gradle, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5571.